# BottomNavigationBar-change the tab icon color

Tags: android, bottomnavigationview

I've integrated Bottom Bar Navigation bar on my app. But when I swipe, tab's color doesn't change. It's weird cause I have selector file. Any idea to solve this problem?

**Activity.java**

```
BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationView = (BottomNavigationView)
            findViewById(R.id.bottom_navigation);


    bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(
            new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
                    switch (item.getItemId()) {
                        case R.id.bb_menu_arac:
                            fragment = new AraclarimFragment();
                            break;
                        case R.id.bb_menu_yaklasan:
                            fragment = new YaklasanlarFragment();
                            break;
                        case R.id.bb_menu_yakin:
                            fragment = new Yakinimdakiler();
                            break;

                    }
                    final FragmentTransaction transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                    transaction.replace(R.id.main_container, fragment).commit();
                    return true;
                }


            });
```

**selector.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:color="@color/beyaz" android:state_enabled="true" />
<item android:color="@color/colorPrimaryDark" android:state_enabled="false" />
</selector>
```

**activiy.xml**

```
<android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
    android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    app:itemBackground="@color/colorPrimary"
    app:itemIconTint="@color/beyaz"
    app:itemTextColor="@color/beyaz"
    app:menu="@menu/bottombar_menu" />
```

Comment: Where have you used selector.xml?

Comment: You've written in code that **androida:state_enabled** instead of **android:state_enabled** ?? Is that making  problem?

Comment: @AnuragSingh ActualIy, I have no idea where should I use or call selector.xml

Comment: @YunusHaznedar you want to change text color for selected item or background of selected item?

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Change  to `app:itemIconTint="@drawable/selector"`

Also change your `selector.xml` to this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_checked="true" android:color="@color/beyaz" />
<item android:color="@color/colorPrimaryDark"  />
</selector>
```

Comment: changing `android:color` to `android:drawable` was the point for me

Answer (score 10):

I was confused about whole process despite reading all the answers, so here is how I resolved it step by step so beginners can understand it properly

Let's say you created `MainActivity` with bottom navigation so

in your `drawable` folder create `bottom_navigation_selector.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item android:state_checked="true" android:color="@color/yourSelectedColor" />
  <item android:color="@color/defaultColor"  />
</selector>
```

then go to the `activity_main.xml` layout and add this line in `BottomNavigationView`

```
app:itemIconTint="@drawable/bottom_navigation_selector"
```

If you also want to change text color accordingly then you need to add this line aswell

```
app:itemTextColor="@drawable/bottom_navigation_selector"
```

Answer (score 4):

You have to set selector as itemIconTint of your BottomNavigationView. Something like

```
 <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
    android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    app:itemBackground="@color/colorPrimary"
    app:itemIconTint="@drawable/selector"
    app:itemTextColor="@color/beyaz"
    app:menu="@menu/bottombar_menu" />
```

Answer (score 1):

I use way @Anurag Singh, but it didn't work until I removed this line:

`navigation?.itemIconTintList = null`

Thank myself.

Answer (score 1):

Just add:
item.setChecked(true);

inside each case;

Answer (score 1):

In BottomNavigationView app:itemIconTint="" provide color not selector

the solution below works for me.

```
bottomNavigationView = findViewById(R.id.bottomNavView);
int[][] states = new int[][] {
        new int[] { android.R.attr.state_selected},
        new int[] {-android.R.attr.state_selected},
        new int[] {-android.R.attr.state_checked},
        new int[] { android.R.attr.state_checked}
};
int[] colors = new int[] {
      ContextCompat.getColor(this,R.color.colorPrimary),
      ContextCompat.getColor(this,R.color.gray),
      ContextCompat.getColor(this,R.color.gray),
      ContextCompat.getColor(this,R.color.colorPrimary)
};
ColorStateList myList = new ColorStateList(states, colors);
bottomNavigationView.setItemIconTintList(myList);//this for item icon 
bottomNavigationView.setItemTextColor(myList);// this for item text
```

create ColorStateList and add tint color programmatically