# Change background color of a selected tab in BottomNavigationView

Tags: android, xml, bottomnavigationview

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_checked="true" android:drawable="@color/SvetloSiva"></item>
    <item android:drawable="@color/bottomBarSiva" />

</selector>
```

Code for drawable navbar.xml

```
<android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
.
.
            android:background="@drawable/navbar"
            app:itemIconTint="@color/NarandzastiTamniji"
            app:itemTextColor="@color/SvetloSiva"
.
.
/>
```

Code for BottomNavigationView. The colors are all specified and different in the colors.xml file.

In the app, it doesn't change the color of the BottomNavigationView items when they are selected. Why?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42346899/bottomnavigationbar-change-the-tab-icon-color

Comment: Possible duplicate of [BottomNavigationBar-change the tab icon color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42346899/bottomnavigationbar-change-the-tab-icon-color)