# Why colour is not changing in the vector?

Tags: android, android-studio, vector

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="24dp"
    android:height="24dp"
    android:viewportHeight="24.0"
    android:viewportWidth="24.0">
    <path
        android:fillColor="#FF408100"
        android:pathData="M10,20v-6h4v6h5v-8h3L12,3 2,12h3v8z" />
</vector>
```

i am dealing with bottomnavigationview i want that the home icon can change its colour initially but it is not working i have already tried restarting and refreshing the pc and one more thing i also want that it change custom color when i click the icon but unable to find out the way without placing other image of same colour in drawable

Any help would be appreciated[home svg is black but colour is set to green](https://i.stack.imgur.com/feDmm.png)

Comment: Hi @Simranjeet Signh, if you're using `BottomNavigationView`, this is the best answer for you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42346899/bottomnavigationbar-change-the-tab-icon-color

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can color custom icons as

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);

    for(int i = 0; i < menu.size(); i++){
        Drawable drawable = menu.getItem(i).getIcon();
        if(drawable != null) {
            drawable.mutate();
            drawable.setColorFilter(Color.parseColor("#FF408100"), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
        }
    }

    return true;
```

}